# Testrunner / Executing unittests for Mono/Monodevelop

Tags: unit-testing, mono, monodevelop

Currently I am experimenting with Mono, and creating a small testproject. When I tried to write some unittests I recognized that there is no default unittest framework like in VS. I decided to go with nUnit (but mbUnit, XUnit,...) would be fine too. 
My problem is, that I was not able to find a testrunner that executes my tests and displays the testresults.

Is there a good tool available (currently I am using Monodevelop 2.4)? It is not a requirement tha it is integrated within monodevelop, so an external tool would be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NUnit is fine. I am using it with mono and works perfectly. For test runner you can use

```
nunit-console [input]
```

or the gui one

```
nunit-gui
```

These apps can be probably installed from your distribution repository (Ubuntu has it for sure) or manually installed using binaries from NUnit site. As you have written, you used to use built in VS tests. If you are using resharper, nunit will integrate as well, I also find it very clean.

I'd like to add that from the gui runner is winforms application and does not look (and feel ;)) too good on my OS. Nevertheless works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this was exactly I was looking for. The installation within ubuntu 11.04 worked.